# how to find latlong from distance?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I want to calculate the estimated location. Suppose i have source (A) and destination (B). Let say vehicle take 18 hours to reach from source to destination. After one hour it departs, the vehicle is at point C. At point C i have speed, Lat Long and distance cover from source (A). let say it cover 100km in 2 hours at point C. At this point i want to calculate the estimated location i.e where the vehicle will be after 2 hours or what will be the location after 300 km from point C with respect to current time,speed ,location and distance at point C. Vehicle is moving along the road. Please help me in this regard. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not actual code but some possible hints to the answer. That's how I would do it.

I assume that you use the [Google Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) and that you know how to calculate a distance between two points from their coordinates.

From this, my idea would be call the API to get your route and to the use the polyline part of the answer. The polyline is encoded with [this algorithm](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/utilities/polylinealgorithm). You can use [this javascript code](http://doublespringlabs.blogspot.jp/2012/11/decoding-polylines-from-google-maps.html) to get your list of points.

You then calculate the distance between each per pair of points from the start. When you reach the distance from point A to point C, you know on which segment of the polyline your vehicle should be. To get the exact coordinates on the segment, I suggest you use the `interpolate` function of the [Google Maps Geometry API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical).

Of course, if your route contains many segments, you might want to use a heuristic such as approximating the search of the middle segment by filtering your list by using a box of coordinates.